# Proving the Basis of a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following problem :

For a vector space $V = \mathbb{C}^2$ with scalar multiplication over $F = \mathbb{R}$, let $W = \{( x_1, x_2) : x_1=ix_2$ and $\bar{x}_2 = -x_2\}$

(a) Prove that W is a subspace of V 

(b) Find a basis for W 
(c) Determine whether $V = W \oplus U $, where
$U = \{( x_1, x_2) : x_1=ix_2$ and $\bar{x}_2 = x_2\}$

For (a), my proof is, roughly, as follows :

(1) ST1 : $0 \in W$

 $x_1 = 0 = ix_2 = i(0) = 0$ therefor $(0,0) \in U$


(2) ST2 : $x+y \in W$ where $x \in W$ and $y \in W$

Let $x_2 = -i$ so that $x = (1, -i) \in W$ and again $x_2 = -2i$ so that $y = (2, -2i) \in W$

Therefor $x + y = (3, -3i) \in W$


(3) ST3 : $cx \in W$ where $c \in F$ and $x \in W$

Let $c=1 \in F$ then $(c)(1, -i) = (1)(1,-i) = (1, -i) \in W$

For (b) I believe, from inspecting (a), that the basis will be $\beta = (1,-i)$ but I'm unsure how to prove this and proceed with (c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really choose your elements for your proof. You have to take an arbitrary element.

ST2 should be:

$(x + y)_1 = ix_2 + iy_2 = i(x_2 + y_2)$

$(x + y)_2 = -\bar{x_2} - \bar{y_2} = -\overline{x_2 + y_2}$

which means that $x+y \in W$

You have to adjust ST3 accordingly.

Your basis looks alright. I don't think you have to proof that.

As a hint for part (c) you just need a counter example.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

For (c), I find that U is also a subspace, satisfying the subspace tests, however the intersection between $U \cap W \neq {0}$ because $\bar{x}_2=-x_2 \neq \bar{x}_2=x_2$. Does that make sense?

Comment: No the intersection is just Zero. Basis for $U$ is for example $(i,1)$. But the direct sum is not V.